# unwanted space after inline block dispite having no spaces in html

Tags: html, css

I know [inline blocks often have unwanted spaces between them because there are spaces in the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements), and that we can set `font-size: 0` or remove the spaces in html to get rid of them. However, it seems like when we're using the `<img>` or `<canvas>` tag (which have `display: inline` by default), we get the unwanted spaces even if we have no spaces in the **html**:

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div style="background-color: pink"><img style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: skyblue" /></div>
</body>
```

The code above looks like this in the browser:

[image: unwanted space after of an inline block]

but if I change it to `<span>` with a character, it does not have the unwanted space:

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div style="background-color: pink"><span style="background-color: skyblue">B</span></div>
</body>
```

[image: no unwanted space after inline block]

I can still get rid of the space in the first one with `font-size: 0` or `line-height: 0`, but **I'm wondering where the space came from**. I even confirmed with javascript that there are no whitespaces in the tag:

```js
document.querySelector("div").innerText // returns ""
```

I've also tried explicitly setting alt="" in case it was some hidden text but it still had the space.

Edit: To clarify, my question is: **why is the space there in the first place?** I'm not looking for CSS tricks to get rid of the space, as I've pointed out two myself in the question already.

Comment: extra space is visible in both examples when you _zoom in_.

Comment: @QuantumX I'm talking about the pink space under the blue rectangle. It should not be visible in the second example. Did you copy the exact example code in the question? Asking because I saw your edit suggestion where you broke the tags into different lines. The bad formatting in my question is intended to not leave any space text in the html. If you break them into their own lines then both examples would have the unwanted space.

Comment: I tried this code in all browser that I have, but all browser shows the same result.

Comment: @QuantumX I'm not sure if we're looking at the same thing. If you click on the "Run code snippet" button of the second code block, the "B" only has blue under it, no pink, like in the original screenshot, regardless of the zoom level. That should be the expected behaviour, as shown by Chris Coyier's Codepen: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/kaEvMk (hence why I was confused when the same behaviour was not observed with `<img>` and `<canvas>`)

Comment: When I run the second snippet (Edge/WIndows10) there is the tiniest bit of pink under the blue. This is nowhere near as big as in the first snippet and I suspect is caused by a sort of rounding error when the system is mapping CSS pixels to screen pixels and the phenomenon is not related to the question @QuantumX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out in the question, setting `font-size: 0` on the div gets rid of the space.

There are various experiments you can try to see what is happening.

For example set div's font-size to 100px - the space gets bigger.

Put the characters 'xg' in the div and you'll see that the image aligns with the bottom of the x. The extra space is used by the g's descender.

The answer from @schmauch solves the problem by making the img have its bottom aligned with the bottom of the div. But the default is to align it with the baseline [of text] even if there isn't any actual text in the div.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the vertical alignment of the image to `vertical-align: bottom` the space vanishes.

Comment: hi @schmauch thank you for the response. it works, but my question is about why the space is there in the first place, given that there are no spaces in the html

Comment: okay after reading @A Haworth's explanation I now understand why you suggested this. I'm marking their answer as the accepted answer because my question was asking for an explanation of the behaviour rather than just a solution